# Why we have used 20 log to convert magnitude into db instead of 10 log?

Tags: acoustics, conventions, intensity

We know that,

$$db = 10 \log P$$
$$=> db = 10 \log X ^2$$
$$=> db = 2*10 \log X$$
$$=> db = 20 \log X$$

Now, my question is, why we use $20 \log$ for converting magnitude into db instead of $10 \log$?

Comment: you've just demonstrated it yourself. 20 log is when the underlying quantity is squared to get a power, such as voltages or currents.

Comment: To follow up on what @Orhym was saying: 20log(x) refers to current and voltage and 10log(x) refers to power. Decibels is just a short hand instead of saying 1000 V/V, you can say 60 dB

Answer (score 3):

The amplitude of a wave is usually not what scientists and engineers care about [1]. They care about the power transfer between systems, whether audio, light, or seismic vibrations. So, their measurements and units are based on power, not wave amplitude. The decibel unit is based on the logarithm of the power. The extra factor of two comes from calculating decibels from the wave amplitude, since power is usually proportional to the square of the wave amplitude.

[1] Surfers care about wave amplitude.

Comment: Everybody who works with linear systems, numerically that is the overwhelming majority of engineers who are building and operating signal processing and transmission systems, cares about the amplitude rather than the power. I, for one, are usually working with dB for amplitudes, which means I am multiplying the logarithm with 20. The only time power comes into play is for power consumption calculations.

Answer (score 1):

$\log x^{2} = 2 \cdot \log x$

$10 \cdot \log x^{2} = 10 \cdot 2 \cdot \log x$

$10 \cdot 2 = 20$.

Just for the record, I, too, was confused by this very thing just recently while working out [field strength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole_field_strength_in_free_space) and [Friis equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friis_transmission_equation) problems.