# Comparing measurements from Sound Level Meters and Audio Recorders

Tags: pressure, acoustics, data-analysis, instrument

I've been working with an environmental sound recording system that consists of a microphone -> sound level meter (SLM) -> digital audio recorder.

Recently I've been involved with implementing a survey where people will listen back to clips from the digital audio record.  Up until now I've always used the SLM to report amplitude measures, but now I'm faced with a situation where I must describe the stimulus that people will be exposed to in the headphones.

I thought I might plot amplitude measures (SLM measures in dBA, audio recorder measures in dBFS) to see how they compared and if there was a well-defined relationship between any of them.  I used the Python Standard Library (audioop) to calculate the peak and RMS values from each clip, and also summarized the numeric values from the SLM for the same time period.

---

The results were surprising to me.  Plots of many different metrics [Lmax vs. RMS power (*shown*), Lmax vs. Peak Sample Value, SEL vs. RMS, SEL vs. Peak] all take a similar form:

[image: Lmax_versus_RMS_power]

They're limited at the top by what appears to be an artifact of the maximum sample value of the audio recorder.  Then, I assume *eventually* there would be a limit on the left-hand side of the plot that would be the noise floor of the Sound Level Meter.

But **what is the physical interpretation of the bound on the right-hand side of the plot?**

I suspect it's along similar lines to this answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/274074/152491, where the measures from the audio recorder are describing power where the SLM is describing amplitude?

---

EDIT:  If it helps, here's a generalized conceptual plot as well:

[image: conceptualized plot from observed data]

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Please take a moment to complete the Tour so you know how this works:   https://physics.stackexchange.com/Tour

Comment: also delving into this on the programmatic side on StackOverflow... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43376507/python-audioop-rms-values-from-power-to-amplitude